# Using BottomNavigationView with a no Theme.AppCompat

Tags: android, android-appcompat, bottomnavigationview

i need to use the theme

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"
```

in an activity where there is a

```
android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
```

but everytime i run the app it crashes because BottomNavigationView need Theme.AppCompat. How can i fix this?

My Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="tfdev.avventuratestuale">

    <application
        android:name=".Main.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
    <activity android:name=".Main.Main.menu_principale"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Main.Main.scene_manager"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
            ></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

BottomNavigationView activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@layout/main_background">

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="#FFFFFF"
        app:itemTextColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

BottomNavigation Activity:

```
public class scene_manager extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scene_manager);



    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed adding

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

in all the activity

Answer (score 1):

Well you can certainly use the `BottomNavigationView` with the Holo theme even though I don't know why you would want to do something like this.

First of all: Not only the BottomNavigationView but also the `AppCompatActivity` from which your `Activity` extends require an AppCompat theme. Following what you need to change in order to make this work:

#### 1 - Extend from Activity not AppCompatActivity

```
public class scene_manager extends Activity {
    // ....
}
```

***Note:*** Class names in Java shouldn't use snake_case but upper camelCase

#### 2 - Apply an AppCompat Theme to the BottomNavigationView directly

```
<RelativeLayout ... >

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        ...
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This way it will work but you'll use certain features like the `Toolbar` since you're not extending AppCompatActivity.

Comment: Sorry - what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. BottomNavigationView requires that you use an AppCompat theme.

One possibility is to use a third-party library that duplicates the functionality you need (instead of using the Google view).